# Remove the List Styles when the Anchor Tag is removed Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem because i am new to HTML and appending anchor tags. My problem is that the style on my list is not being removed when the appended anchor tag is removed.

And another is that when it loads, even the marker is not present on Google Maps, it still shows on the list until I move it a little bit and it is removed on the maps.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="map2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="results1">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <ul id="places1"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Code

```
function codeAddress() {
    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        map: map,
        shadowStyle: 0,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        arrowSize: 15,
        maxWidth: 300,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        arrowPosition: 50,
        arrowStyle: 0
    });
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadCustomerList', function Geocode(address) {
        $.each(address, function () {
            var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
            var Name = this["Name"];
            var clientID = this["ClientID"];
            var ID = this["ID"];
            var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
            var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
            var LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                position: LatLang,
                title: currVal
            })

            var link = $('<a href="#">' + currVal + '</a>')
                .data('location', LatLang);
            $('#places').append($('<li id=\'List1\' class=\'List1\'>').append(link));
            link.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(address[0], "click");
                infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Customer/CustomerDetails?clientCusId=' + ID + '&clientId=' + clientID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                $('#places').find('li a').css('display', function () {
                    return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))

                    ? '' : 'none';
                });
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                    infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Customer/CustomerDetails?clientCusId=' + ID + '&clientId=' + clientID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, currVal));
            address.push(marker);

        })
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
    });
}
```

I hope someone can Help me with this kind of problem...

Here is the Screenies:
[image: When it loads]

[image: Then when i moved a littlebit]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to remove? The whole "Results" container? Can you provide a working link to the page?

Comment: @MrUpsidown sorry sir i cannot show a working link. . .i want to remove the Styles . .  when there is no Item on list. . The Gray one

Comment: Can you show the HTML output when the list is empty? And what is the class you use to grey the rows?

Comment: @MrUpsidown when the List is empty the anchor tags class turns to `display:none` , The gray rows is just `<li>`

Comment: It would still be good if we see the HTML/CSS.

Comment: I can see you are creating a `<li>` with `id="List1"`. Don't you end up with multiple `<li>` with the same id?

Comment: @MrUpsidown yeah , im ending up with `<li>` with same id

Comment: @MrUpsidown updated the Codes, Added the HTML

Comment: Well, then you should correct the multiple IDs, that's a start because this is incorrect markup. Then you seem to be applying the grey class to the `<li>` and hiding the `<a>` tag within it. In this case, of course, the class applied to the `<li>` will still be there. Why not just remove/hide the `<li>`?

Comment: @MrUpsidown can you provide me a sample code. . . im new to this kind of problem and it bother me every now and then :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46143/discussion-between-ren-tao-and-mrupsidown)